# How to make <li> editable on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make it possible that when the user clicks on `+` the `<li>` element that it's located inside becomes like an editable input form, where a new menu item name can be created and saved (by entering the name and clicking Enter).

The code of the current item is

```
<li id="addNewContext" class="menu-item-divided"><a href="javascript:">+</a></li>
```

Is there a snippet of code I could use to make that field editable that could save the name entered into an array, which I can then use to repopulate the menu?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: I would start by doing 1)get text of li with jquery 2)change the html of the li to a text input with the current value of li 3)on lose focus read the input and change the li html to the text from that input, also stackoverflow is ideally like "I tried this and didn't work" and you didn't try anything at this point

Comment: Warning! If you make an element contentEditable, then someone can paste in almost anything they like, much more than just specifying the textual contents of a new list item. It just depends on whether that's what you want or not.

Answer (score 6):

HTML5 allows for a ContentEditable attribute to be added to any HTML element. Assign a function to the onclick event for the list item, and make it set the ContentEditable attribute to true.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
var editList = document.querySelector('.edit-list');

editList.onclick = function() {
  
  //or you can use list.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  list.contentEditable = true;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li><span class="edit-list">+</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/b8m35wwk/1/

Comment: 1+ But better use the property instead of the attribute: `list.contentEditable = true;`. And consider using [stack snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: Updated the post so it used a stack snippet as well!

Comment: There are an error in your post, clicking the + makes the whole list editable, no just the + item. OP sayd : *when the user clicks on + the <li> element that it's located inside becomes like an editable input form*

Comment: I assume he wants to use it to add an additional item to the list (hence the plus sign), so I made it make the list itself editable. Otherwise, as it is, it would just let you edit the content of the list item containing the + sign. OP can deal with the logistics of which item to select and creating a function that adds additional list items. This is just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make it possible that when the user clicks on + the `<li>` element that it's located inside becomes like an editable input form, where a new menu item name can be created and saved (by entering the name and clicking Enter).

This sample also remove `+` sign on click:

```js
$('#addNewContext')

// on click, make content editable.
.click(function() {
    $(this).html("").attr('contenteditable', 'true');
})

// on hit enter, 
.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     var val = $(this).text();
     $(this)
        // create a new li item
        .before("<li>" + val + "</li>")
        // set plus sign again
        .html("+")
        // make contenteditable to false, when clicked the process start again.
        .attr('contenteditable', 'false');
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>not edit me</li>
  <li>not edit me</li>
  <li>not edit me</li>
  <li>not edit me</li>
  <li id="addNewContext" class="menu-item-divided">+</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use contentEditable

```html
let list_1_e = document.getElementById('addNewContext');
list_1_e.contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thaks